# VS Code cannot find module in Vue + TypeScript project, WebStorm has no problem

Tags: typescript, vue.js, visual-studio-code

VS Code cannot find the module below, but it can be used in my project:

[image: VSCode screenshot]

However, it can be found in WebStorm:

[image: WebStorm screenshot]

This is my tsconfig:

[image: tsconfig]

Comment: What does your tsconig.json look like ?

Comment: my question has updated, show my tsconfig.json

Comment: i have found the problem , it's vetur's bug

Answer (score 2):

it's vetur's bug, it will validat the script in .vue, and it will error if the script's lang is ts

Comment: What a life saver. I've been staring at `<script setup>` and not able to figure out why the template wasn't showing any errors when I used the wrong variable name. `<script setup lang="ts">` fixed it.